# Why linebreaks break the line height within certain environments with size-changing macros?

Tags: macros, line-breaking, environments

Why linebreaks break the line height within certain environments with size-changing macros?

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between these three approaches:

1. `\newenvironment`
2. between `{}` or `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`
3. inside a `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{With newenvironment}

\newenvironment{env}{\begin{center}\LARGE}{\end{center}}
\begin{env}
  Text with\\linebreak
\end{env}

\section{With begin/endgroup}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE
Text with\\linebreak}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begingroup
\LARGE
Text with\\linebreak
\endgroup
\end{center}

\section{With minipage}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
  \LARGE
  Text with\\linebreak
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens with the first example:

```
\begin{center}
{\LARGE
Text with\\linebreak}
\end{center}
```

You open a group (`\begin`) and order TeX to center lines; in this environment `\\` is just `\par` with some code added to make it obey the usual syntax with `*`-variant and optional spacing argument.

Then you open another group with `{` (with `\begingroup` it would be the same, as long as the group is ended with `\endgroup` instead of `}`) in which you issue the `\LARGE` command.

The fact that `\\` does `\par` means that two paragraphs are typeset; the first is set with the baselineskip pertaining to `\LARGE`. But the second (with the word `linebreak` not: indeed the `center` environment issues a `\par` to finish off the environment, but this `\par` comes along when the group started with `{` has ended and *the font size command has been undone*. So the second paragraph is typeset with the baselineskip that is in force when the `\end{center}` is seen, that is, the value it had when the `center` environment was started. The lines don't overlap because TeX doesn't normally do it (1pt of vertical space will be between the two lines, more precisely the value of `\lineskip`).

How to solve the issue? Being simple!

```
\begin{center}
\LARGE
Text with\\
linebreak
\end{center}
```

The inner group does nothing good and something bad. The group opened by `\begin` is closed by `\end`, so the setting of `\LARGE` will be undone anyway.

If you do it with your `env` environment, you just add a grouping, but

```
\begin{env}
Text with\\
linebreak
\end{env}
```

will work correctly, because it essentially resolves into

```
\begingroup
\begin{center}
\LARGE
Text with\\
linebreak
\end{center}
\endgroup
```

(the outer group is provided by `\begin{env}` and `\end{env}`), so what I said above applies.

Adding a `minipage` is probably not what you want: just look at the output of this example to see why:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{center}
\LARGE
Text with\\
linebreak
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\LARGE
Text with\\
linebreak
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the spacing different? The `minipage` in the right column has large height and depth, so above and below the minipage TeX uses the `\lineskip` glue, while in the left column the stated values of `\baselineskip` are used.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you're not doing the same with each component. The environment `env` and `minipage` all have a scope for `\LARGE` that is ended by the environment as a `\par`. It's this paragraph delimiter that sets the entire contents - *including* the baseline skip - in the appropriate font.

To remedy this in your example, issue a par within the extent of the font formatting command `\LARGE`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{With newenvironment}

\newenvironment{env}{\begin{center}\LARGE}{\end{center}}
\begin{env}
  Text with\\linebreak
\end{env}

\section{With begin/endgroup}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE
Text with\\linebreak\par}% <---- Added \par
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begingroup
\LARGE
Text with\\linebreak\par% <---- Added \par
\endgroup
\end{center}

\section{With minipage}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
  \LARGE
  Text with\\linebreak
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Adding `\par`? Sorry, no.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand "sorry, no". Surely in the bigger scheme of things the use of `\par` when working in grouped scope suffices. My assumption from the OP's post was a very particular case and not necessarily localized to an environment that contains *only* 2 lines of code in a different font. Your approach is merely to suggesting removing the grouping inside the environment.

Comment: The right way is to remove the additional grouping. Or using ``\\``, as you're in `center`.