# Behavior of \\ inside center environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

While trying to compile a title page for my dissertation I realized that I do not understand the behavior of `\\`. Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\Huge\bfseries%
    Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Dragons
  }% Title
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which yields a bad spacing before the last line. It seems like either:

```
{\Huge\bfseries%
  Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
  Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
  Victory Against the\\[0.5\baselineskip]
  Dragons
}% Title
```

or

```
{\Huge\bfseries%
  Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
  Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
  Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
  Dragons\\
}% Title
```

can serve as a workaround. Neither of them is intuitive for me.

- What is the right way to handle the line breaks here (with a manually tuned vertical spacing)?
- Why is it happening? [Teach me how to fish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). Why `\\` behaves this way? Where is it *documented*?

Comment: You have to issue a `\par`agraph in order to have it properly set with the font selection in place. So, insert `\par` at the end, within the braced group, to have the desired effect. This is discussed to some extent in [Why linebreaks break the line height within certain environments with size-changing macros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134943/5764)

Answer (score 14):

The following is taken from [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) (section **17.2.1 Ending a paragraph and a group at the same time**, p 167):

> If a paragraph is set in a group, 
>   it may be necessary to ensure that the `\par` ending
>   the paragraph occurs inside the group.
>   The parameters influencing the typesetting of the paragraph,
>   such as the `\leftskip` and the `\baselineskip`,
>   are only looked at when the paragraph is finished.
>   Thus finishing off a paragraph with
>
> ```
> ... last words.}\par
> ```
>
> causes the values to be used
>   that prevail outside the group, instead of those inside.
>
> Better ways to end the paragraph are
>
> ```
> ... last words.\par}
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> ... last words.\medskip}
> ```
>
> In the second example the vertical command `\medskip`
>   causes the `\par` token to be inserted.

From this it is clear that you should finish a paragraph before the group ends. However, since `center` forms a group itself, it's simplest to use

```
\begin{center}
  \Huge\bfseries%
    Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Dragons
\end{center}
```

and avoid the group/`\par` problem.

---

Another thing to realise is that the `center` environment redefines the way `\\` works. The following is taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) (which [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses as-is) - I've added some comments:

```
\message{center,}
\def\@centercr{\ifhmode \unskip\else \@nolnerr\fi
       \par\@ifstar{\nobreak\@xcentercr}\@xcentercr}% \@centercr is \par (with more stuff)
\def\@xcentercr{\addvspace{-\parskip}\@ifnextchar
    [\@icentercr\ignorespaces}
\def\@icentercr[#1]{\vskip #1\ignorespaces}
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}% \begin{center}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}% \end{center}
\def\centering{% Called when using \begin{center}
  \let\\\@centercr% \\ is redefined to be \@centercr
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
```

It's clear that `\\` in `center` is similar to `\par`, giving rise to one work-around you mention

```
{
  ...
  Dragons\\
}% Title
```

Answer (score 9):

do not use the `{..}` inside of the `center` environment, it is already local. And then you'll get a proper `\par` at the end of the `center` environment (done by the environment itself):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \Huge\bfseries%
    Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Dragons
\end{center}

default font size and shape
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

everyone else has already given the obvious correct answer -- the group needs to be
ended with `\par`.

but since it's also desired to open up the baseline uniformly, the example can be
simplified:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\Huge\bfseries
   \baselineskip=1.25\baselineskip
    Eat fresh tires to\\
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\
    Victory Against the\\
    Dragons
    \par
  }% Title
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually did something very similar. BTW: I guess this changes the `\baselineskip` only inside the `{...}`, right? How can I save the current value of `\baselineskip`?

Comment: yes, the change to `\baselineskip` is local within a group.  to save a skip, you need a "skip register": `\newskip\mybaselineskip`.  then to set it for use outside a group, `\global\mybaselineskip=\baselineskip` should do it.  (okay, this is basic tex syntax; there is probably a more latex-y way to do it, but i'm afraid i'm "old school".)

Answer (score 4):

It is one of the common mistakes discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139898/19356). I quote it again here to make it long enough as a comment.

### Forgot to break the paragraph before the closing `}`

When a paragraph  has font size change, the `\par` must be invoked before `}`

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\foo{%
These dummy texts will span more than 2 lines. If you see they do not span more than 2 lines then you have to inform me now!}

\begin{document}
\parindent=5em\relax
\foo

{\huge \foo}

\foo

{\huge \foo\par}

\foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because the paragraph inside environment is not ended. I hope one of the following (equivalent) solutions will be intuitive for you.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\Huge\bfseries%
    Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Dragons

  }% Title
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  {\Huge\bfseries%
    Eat fresh tires to\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Get Ready to the Ultimate\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Victory Against the\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    Dragons\par
  }% Title
\end{center}
```

[image]